# AngularJS - Setting dynamic key names

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set key names of the `Object` dynamic. Here is my code:-

```
if (fieldName == 'DEPARTMENT') {
   var objCombos = []; 
   objCombos = $scope.getValues ('DEPARTMENT');
}
if (fieldName == 'DESIG') {
   var objCombos = []; 
   objCombos = $scope.getValues ('DESIG');
}

$scope.getValues = function (fieldName) {            
        var objDepart= [];
        jq.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Data/getValuesWithId?fieldName=" + fieldName,
            async: false,
            success: function (result) {
                angular.forEach(result, function (value, key) {                                               
                   objDepart.push({ id: key, fieldName: value });
                   // This is what i expect { 'id' : 11, 'DEPARTMENT': value }
                   // The key of 2nd element is dynamic(DEPARTMENT, DESIG, etc)
                });
            }
        });
        return objDepart;
    }
```

How to set keys dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**Bracket notation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
 var obj = { id: key};
 obj[fieldName] = value; //Use Bracket notation
 objDepart.push(obj);
```